# Laravel won't run on xampp but works when served

Tags: laravel

I'm getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or \\ (T_NS_SEPARATOR) in D:\xampp\htdocs\praxxys\vendor\myclabs\deep-copy\src\DeepCopy\deep_copy.php on line 5
```

When I try to run my app on xampp but it runs fine when I use artisan serve

here's my composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
},
```

Comment: Make sure you're using the correct PHP version in XAMPP, the line that is erroring seems to be `use function function_exists;` and `use function` requires PHP 5.6+ so there's a chance you run the correct PHP binary when you call `php serve` but XAMPP is using a different one

Comment: How do i fix it? My php version is 5.5

Comment: I tried changing the php folder to my downloaded php 5.6 but apache won't start

Comment: It's probably easier if you just upgrade XAMPP. I'm not all that experienced with XAMPP so I don't really know the details

Answer (score 1):

if you want to access laravel project without running artisan serve, you need to change few settings,

open `httpd-vhosts.conf` which is located within `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`

Add following code snippet:

```
<VirtualHost laravel.test:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel_Projects\firstProject\public"
    ServerAdmin laravel.dev
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel_Projects\firstProject">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This enables Apache server to listen to **laravel.test**, We now need to redirect **laravel.test** to **localhost**. To do so, edit the hosts file. It is located within `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`.

Also, make sure that you open the file as an Administrator. Add:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
# 127.0.0.1 localhost
# ::1 localhost

127.0.0.1 laravel.test
```

Save the file and restart the system if required. You can then test the application with `laravel.test` in the browser